# After selecting a date and try to console log it it shows undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angularfire

```
 <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <input [(ngModel)]="date" id="date" name="date" class="form-control" required/>
 </div>

$(function () {
    $('#date').datetimepicker({
       format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm' 
    });
});
```

I'm using angular js after I choose a date and try to `console.log` the value it shows Undefined but when I modify it and `console.log` the value it shows the string inside the input

Comment: Show your code with `console.log`'s

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [(ngModel)] is used in Angular 2, not AngularJS. In Angular 2 you have to use the command ng-model.

Second, ng-model binds the date to a $scope variable called `date`. If you want to access the date in a controller, use `$scope.date` inside of your controller.

Third, you should never use JQuery to get variables from your view. Mixing up JavaScript frameworks like JQuery and AngularJS will might cause problems. It is also very messy code style.